# install4j change content of a Button

Tags: install4j

I have a install4j Project. It wprks fine but i found a little Error and dont know how to fix it.

In my Project i saw that on the File Chooser Window the Buttons are in two languages. I want German and the whole Project is set to German.

How can i chance that the content of 1. Button is German and the 2. is english? i did not found any option in screen configuration

[image: File Chooser]

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug, it will be fixed in 7.0.5. You can contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already fixed.

As a temporary workaround, define the i18n message `ButtonSelect` in a custom localization file on the "General Settings->Languages" step and set it to the German text.